# About the fluid friction along the wall in pipes

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, friction, flow, viscosity

I wonder how can the friction between a fluid and a wall in a cylindrical pipe can be calculated. Is there any theory that I can refer to? I also want to check if there's any relation between the diameter of the pipe, the velocity and the temperature of the fluid and friction.

Comment: You are asking about the boundary layer https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boundary_layer and for laminar flow through a pipe Poiseuille's equation http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/ppois.html might be useful.  The temperature dependence will probably be mainly due to the change in the viscosity of the fluid as viscosity is very temperature dependent.

Answer (score 1):

We know that adhesive forces bound fluid particles at the surface of the pipe. The rest of the fluid will not be affected by this force. But force acting on the remaining fluid is viscous force. The below figure shows relationship between velocity profile and radius of pipe. Where n is coefficient of viscosity.[image]

Even if the fluid is a gas, we can still see the effects of viscous and frictional forces at the surface of the pipe, but with different values.

Comment: Your last paragraph is incorrect. Gases behave the same way that liquids do. They just have different values of density, viscosity, etc.

Comment: Ha yes, Thanks for that!